# Extended Tonelli's Theorem

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, fubini-tonelli-theorems

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{C}$ be a measurable sign changing function with $f = f^+ - f^-$ such that $f^+,f^-\geq 0$ and:
$$ \int f^+ =\infty $$
$$ \int f^- < \infty $$
Can one still apply Tonelli's theorem in this case?

Comment: I thought to apply Fubini the function has to be $L^1$?

Comment: But $\int f^+= \infty$ by my assumption

Answer (score 0):

We can apply Tonelli's Theroem to $f^{+}$, Fubini's Theorem to $f^{-}$ and subtract to conclude that $\int f(x,y)dxdy=\int f(x,y)dydx=\infty$.